# Custom checkable / toggleble QFrame widget

Tags: c++, css, qt, widget, qframe

How can I make a custom widget (derived from "QFrame") contain a support to be checkable/toggleble?
How to make Qt's stylesheet (CSS) to be aware that my widget was checked/toggled by user?

Is there some kind of signal or property that I need to use in my custom widget?

I don't want to use (i.e.) QPushButton because I need my button widget to use Qt's .ui file.

I.e. when using QPushButton - things are simple:

```
QPushButton#btnName:focus:pressed { border-image: url(ThemesPathKey/menu-top-h.png);    }
QPushButton#btnName:checked {   border-image: url(ThemesPathKey/menu-top-h.png);    }
QPushButton#btnName:hover { border-image: url(ThemesPathKey/menu-top-h.png);    }
```

I need something similar for my custom button widget.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hover` and `focus` for a custom widget, but `checked` is supported for buttons and check boxes only.

To replace `checked` you can use a custom property:

```
QPushButton#btnName[checked="true"] {   border-image: url(ThemesPathKey/menu-top-h.png);    }
```

when your widget is clicked toggle `checked` property like this:

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*) override
{
    bool checked = property("checked").toBool();
    setProperty("checked", !checked);
    style()->polish(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ezee. 
This is the best way I can think of so far.. 
Just was really interested ("just for sport") if there is any way to replicate same "checked" action as used in QPushButton.
(To use "QFrame#btnName:checked { }" instead of "QFrame#btnName[checked="true"] { }")

Comment: It you want to use a widget different from `QAbstractButton` descendant this is the only way, but you can inherit from `QAbstractButton` and implement your own appearance. In this way I believe you'll be able to manage to use `:checked`.

Comment: For "QAbstractButton" you would need to implement your own "paintEvent".
And I believe this type of widget would not be usable as a "promotable" widget in the "Qt Creator".
Anyway, thanks for the help! I will stick with using "setProperty".

Answer (score 1):

For hovering, you could use the same approach with any derived widget:

```
class MyClass : public QFrame
{
<...>
}

MyClass a;
a.setStyleSheet("MyClassa:hover{<...>}"); //this will work
a.setStyleSheet("MyClass#a:hover{<...>}"); //and this will work
a.setStyleSheet("QFrame:hover{<...>}"); //Even this will work, too
```

Checking/unchecking is more complex. Frames do not have check states, so you'll have to implement it yourself.

```
class MyClass : public QFrame
{
public:
    <...>
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * e) override
    {
        checked_ = !checked_;        
        if(checked)
            setStyleSheet("border:1px solid black;");
        else
            setStyleSheet("border:0px;"); 
    }
bool checked_;
}
```

or something like this

```
class MyClass : public QFrame
{
public:
    <...>
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e) override
    {
        if(checked)
        {
        //draw something
        }
        else
        {
        //draw something else
        }
    }
    bool checked_;
}
```

Comment: Thanks SingerOfTheFall, but I would love to find a way to use this not modifying styleSheet.